# How do I solve $\mathbf{x}^\top e^{t\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{y}=c$ for $t$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have the following matrix equation:

$\mathbf{x}^\top e^{t\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{y}=c$

$\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are vectors of length $k$, $\mathbf{A}$ is a $k\times k$ matrix, and $c$ and $t$ are scalars. $e^{t\mathbf{A}}$ is the matrix exponential of $t\mathbf{A}$.

I want to solve for $t$. Is this possible analytically?

I don't think these extra details simplify the solution, but here they are anyway: $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of probabilities that sum to $1$.
$\mathbf{y}$ is a vector of zeroes except for the $i$th element which is $1$.
$\mathbf{A}$ is a transition intensity matrix, whose rows sum to zero.

Comment: This in general boils down to an equation of the form $a_1e^{t\lambda_1}+\cdots+a_ne^{t\lambda_n}=c$. I don't think there is any closed-form solution.